# Firebase web - close connection to the realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase on the web, with Javascript.
**how can I close the connection to the realtime DB** ?

```
var config = {....};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// get the firebase DB reference
var db = firebase.database().ref();

//doing something
db.push(....);

// close the firebase connection ???
db.close() || firebase.disconnect() || or something like that...
```

Tried lots of functions - goOffline() , close() , ect.
But nothing does the trick.

Any help would be appreciated...
tnx mates

Comment: Calling `goOffline()` will close the connection between the client and the database. How did you come to the conclusion that calling it doesn't close the connection?

Comment: goOffline on the firebase object or the databaseREF ? can u add a code? maybe i'm not implementing it right .. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 8):

Try this-

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Kill this firebase app.
firebase.app().delete().then(function() {
  firebase.initializeApp(newConfig);
});
```

goOffline() will close connection but Firebase will continue to work locally and the app will remain in memory.

Comment: how to reconnect bro?

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
firebaseRef.off();
```

This will end your connection with firebase and stop communicating with the database.

Answer (score 1):

For JSv9, as @Frank van Puffelen said, calling `goOffline(db)`

> Disconnects from the server (all Database operations will be completed offline).

Quoted from [Official Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#gooffline).

Note that the `db` here is a `Database` instead of a `DatabaseRef`.
Maybe you didn't call it in the correct way.

I looked up for this for this `jest` error: `A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.` (I made a note [here in my knowledgebase](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/Firebase-Learning-Note#test-realtime-db-with-jest).) And adding a `goOffline(db)` in `afterAll()` actually solved it.

Answer (score 0):

For others' information, this is how I disconnect firebase once I fetched needed data.

```js
import {
  getDatabase,
  goOnline,
  goOffline,
  get,
  child,
  ref,
} from 'firebase/database';

// something like this
const db = getDatabase()
try {
  goOnline(db);
  const snapshot = await get(child(ref(db), `visitors/${id}`));
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const data = snapshot.val();
  } else {
    console.log('No data available');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', error);
}
goOffline(db);
```

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are trying to do this operation server side with CLIENT SIDE conf.

Have you set up correctly the config for you firebase.initializeApp({}) correctly as a server?

Look at the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-authentication

We had the same issue, but all this disappear when when we correctly set up everything as per the documentation and using it with the "Authenticate with limited privileges" .

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: please note - how you close the connection to the realtime DB ?

Comment: Firebase has now release a server side package->

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

It should solve the issue.